Deriving the Black-Scholes-Merton Formula for Time-Varying Interest Rate **and** Volatility
I'm currently working on an exercise from my textbook, which involves deriving the Black-Scholes-Merton formula under the assumptions of time-varying interest rates and volatilities. The exercise is stated as follows:

Exercise 5.4 (Black-Scholes-Merton formula for time-varying, non-random interest rate and volatility):
Consider a stock whose price differential is given by:
$$
dS(t) = r(t) S(t) dt + \sigma(t) S(t) dW(t),
$$
where $ r(t) $ and $ \sigma(t) $ are non-random functions of time, and $ W(t) $ is a Brownian motion under the risk-neutral measure $ \mathbb{P} $. Let $ T > 0 $ be given, and consider a European call option with strike price $ K $, whose value at time zero is:
$$
c(0, S(0)) = \mathbb{E} \left[ e^{-\int_0^T r(t) dt} (S(T) - K)^+ \right].
$$

Show that $ S(T) $ is of the form $ S(0) e^X $, where $ X $ is a normal random variable, and determine the mean and variance of $ X $.

Let:


$$
\text{BSM}(T, x; K, R, \Sigma) = x N \left( \frac{1}{\Sigma \sqrt{T}} \left[\log \frac{x}{K} + (R + \frac{\Sigma^2}{2}) T \right] \right) - e^{-R T} K N \left( \frac{1}{\Sigma \sqrt{T}} \left[\log \frac{x}{K} + (R - \frac{\Sigma^2}{2}) T \right] \right)
$$
denote the value at time zero of a European call option expiring at time $ T $ when the underlying stock has constant volatility $ \Sigma $ and the interest rate $ R $ is constant. Show that:
$$
c(0, S(0)) = \text{BSM} \left( S(0), T, \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T r(t) dt, \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt} \right).
$$

For part (i), I believe I need to express $ S(T) $ as an exponential of a normally distributed random variable. For part (ii), I suspect it involves using the definition of the Black-Scholes formula with appropriately averaged parameters, but I'm having trouble seeing the connection.
Could anyone guide me through the steps to derive these results?

Duplicate.

This question is similar to: Black-Scholes model with time-dependent volatility. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@KurtG.
This question clearly has a time varying interest rate while the one you linked does not. Try to pay a little more attention to the details before you comment.

@Dominique
Same feedback for you.

Before you lecture fellow MSE users about paying attention I suggest you perform a little exercise: calculate the expectation of $\exp(-\int_0^tr(s),ds)(S_t-K)^+$ where $S_t$ is $$S_0\exp\left(\int_0^tr(s),ds+\int_0^t\sigma(s),dW_s-\frac12\int_0^t\sigma^2(s),ds\right),.$$ If you want do do that in a smart way, replace $\int_0^tr(s),ds$ by $Rt$ and the variance $\int_0^t\sigma^2(s),ds$ by $\Sigma^2t$ (with two constants $R,\Sigma,.$ Now tell me if there is anything that makes the task more complicated than if we started with constant rates and vol from the beginning.

@KurtG. You really should pay more attention. The question is already answered below. This is not a duplicate. Stay mad.

@user1474709: I'm sorry for my mistake and I have voted to reopen your question.

I had noticed that the question was answered below. Perhaps someone else should have paid more attention from the very beginning. Since we are on the road to reopening the question I am looking forward to learning something that I might have missed in 35 years of working with BSM.

@MarkViola I have already upvoted your question. Thank you for your time and actually trying to help.

You're welocme.  My pleasure.  And feel free to accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

We begin with the SDE
$$dS(t) = r(t) S(t)\, dt + \sigma(t) S(t)\, dW(t)$$
Let $x(t) =\log(S(t))$.  Using Itoh's Lemma, we have
$$dx(t) =\left(r(t)-\frac12 \sigma^2(t)\right)\,dt+\sigma(t)\,dW(t)\tag1$$
Integrating $(1)$ from $t$ to $T$ we find that
$$x(T)=x(t)+\int_t^T\left(r(t')-\frac12 \sigma^2(t')\right)\,dt'+\int_t^T \sigma(t')\,dW(t')\tag2$$
Hence, we see from exponentiating $(2)$ that
$$S(T)=e^{x(T)}$$
where $x(T)$ is disrtibuted normally with expected value given by
$$E_t\left(x(T)\right)=x(t)+\int_t^T\left(r(t')-\frac12 \sigma^2(t')\right)\,dt'\tag3$$
and variance given by
$$\text{Var}_t\left(x(T)\right)=\int_t^T \sigma^2(t')\,dt'\tag4$$
From $(3)$ and $(4)$, we see that we can replace $R$ with $\frac1{T-t}\int_t^T r(t')\,dt'$ and $\Sigma^2$ with $\frac1{T-t}\int_t^T \sigma(t')\,dt'$ in the BSM equation.
And we are done!

Pretty sure this is from Stochastic Calculus for Finance II (Shreve)
A few observations:

In the first equation for $ c(0, S(0)) $, $ E \rightarrow \tilde{E} $. (Risk-neutral measure)

In the second equation for $ c(0, S(0)) $, the variable for BSM should be:
$$
  BSM \left( T, S(0); K, \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T r(t) dt, \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt} \right).
  $$


Part (i)
Proof:
Define $$
 d \ln S_t = \frac{dS_t}{S_t} = r dt + \sigma \tilde{dW_t}- \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 dt $$
Then
$$ S_T = S_0 \exp \left[ \int_0^T \left( r_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t^2 \right) dt + \int_0^T \sigma_t \tilde{dW_t} \right]. $$
Define
$$
X = \int_0^T \left( r_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t^2 \right) dt + \int_0^T \sigma_t \tilde{dW_t}.
$$
The first term in the expression of $ X $ is a number, and the second term is a Gaussian random variable $ N(0, \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt) $, since both $ r $ and $ \sigma $ are deterministic. Therefore,
$$
S_T = S_0 e^X,
$$
with $ X \sim N \left( \int_0^T \left( r_t - \frac{1}{2} \sigma_t^2 \right) dt, \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt \right) $.
Part (ii)
Proof:
For the standard BSM model with constant volatility $ \Sigma $ and interest rate $ R $, under the risk-neutral measure, we have
$$
S_T = S_0 e^Y,
$$
where $$ Y = \left( R - \frac{1}{2} \Sigma^2 \right) T + \Sigma \tilde{W_T} \sim N \left( (R - \frac{1}{2} \Sigma^2) T, \Sigma^2 T \right),$$
and
$$
\tilde{E}[(S_0 e^Y - K)^+] = e^{-RT} BSM(T, S_0; K, R, \Sigma).
$$
Note
$ R = \frac{1}{T} E[Y] + \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(Y) $ and $ \Sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \text{Var}(Y)} $
, we can get:
$$
\tilde{E}[(S_0 e^Y - K)^+] = E[e^{Y + \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(Y)}] BSM \left( T, S_0; K, \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T r_t dt, \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt} \right).
$$
So, for the model in this problem:
$$
c(0, S_0) = e^{-\int_0^T r_t dt} \tilde{E}[(S_0 e^X - K)^+]
$$
$$
= e^{-\int_0^T r_t dt} E[e^{X + \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(X)}] BSM \left( T, S_0; K, \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T r_t dt, \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt} \right)
$$
$$
= BSM \left( T, S_0; K, \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T r_t dt, \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \sigma^2(t) dt} \right).
$$

@MarkViola Personally, I found this answer more detailed. I'm also not an expert though.

@MarkViola Upvoted your answer.
